# HTML output in SAS

Tags: sas

I only see results of my SAS programs in Log like:

```
16488  title '6'; 
16489 
16490  ods html file = 'E:\Dev\ka\body1.html'; 
16491 
16492 
16493  proc means data=learn.blood; 
16494      var RBC WBC; 
16495      output out = means mean = M_RBC M_WBC; 
16496  run;
```

It's not show any error, but I don't see results in html file.

How to turn on html output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the setting 'Show results as they are generated' off.
Check your preference settings.

Confirm your HTML file is created as well, though you may need to include a CLOSE before it is fully available.

```
ods html file = 'E:\Dev\ka\body1.html' 

proc means data=sashelp.class; 
var height weight; 
output out=means mean=M_Height M_Weight; 
run;

ods html close;
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me.  I adapted your code slightly to test it:

```
ods html file="%sysfunc(pathname(work))\body1.html"; 

proc means data=sashelp.class; 
  var height weight; 
  output out=means mean=M_Height M_Weight; 
run;

%put Your file has been output to: %sysfunc(pathname(work))\body1.html;
```

I am seeing results.  Are you sure you have observations in your dataset and that there are no errors or warnings being printed to the log?